# CSS3 animation iteration count 1 vs infinite chrome compatibility

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

Ok. I tried to search for this question. and it's very simple. I have a css swing animation working good in firefox but not in chrome. Of course, I added the webkit prefix. but still no luck. I changed the iteration count to infinite and finally it is working, but no I don't want it to run infinitely. Is this really a bug? does anybody find a solution? here's the link to the code I made in jsfiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/7t1uvyup/2/ and here's the actual code.

```css
.x{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
}
.x:hover
{
        -webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
        animation: swing 1s ease;
       /* change webkit iteration count to infinite and it will work on chrome but of course with infinite animation */
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
       transform: translateX(-5px);
    } 
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
        transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

Comment: It's working the same in Firefox as it is for Chrome on my end.

Comment: thanks for that info. I will try re-install my chrome.

Comment: I just tried re-installing twice. and it's still not working.. what do you think is the problem?

Comment: What exactly is the difference you are seeing? Are you using the latest browser versions? Firefox 35 and Chrome 40?

Comment: yes version 40.0.2214.91 for chrome.. and div is not moving or anything
but in firefox it is working fine.

Comment: Works fine for me as well. Btw., it doesn’t make the most sense to use the `-webkit`-prefixed version of the transform properties in the non-prefixed `@keyframes` declaration and vice versa. (It probably doesn’t hurt, but you are writing an unnecessary large amount of code.)

Comment: I know that.. it just copied it somewhere to test things up.. and here's another question. and I think we are having the same issue..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901272/webkit-animation-iteration-count-bug-in-chrome

Comment: and it seems every piece of css animation with iteration count, does not work in my chrome browser. as you can see I have re-installed twice and everything is in default. but still I am having the same result. it only works with infinite iteration.

Comment: I did some research.. CSS is Hardware-Accelerated. meaning to say this has nothing to do with my browser but my desktop. I got my graphic card broken a few weeks ago. and haven't been replaced yet. but how it works in firefox? poor google chrome. 

in this case I guess javascript and jquery win this animation test over css. 

and firefox over chrome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research.. CSS is Hardware-Accelerated..

So this is not just a weird random bug.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem just now. To me it seems that the animation takes place in very short period of time and many times it is not noticable to human eyes; i.e. Chrome does not respect animation duration parameter when webkit-animation-iteration-count is not infinite.

To me it doesn't seem to be a random bug. It is reliably reproducible.

Try visiting http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp with different browsers. Chrome shows the worst performance; CSS3 animation box does not animate; it just stays.

Comment: Are you using chrome in microsoft windows as well? coz I tried this test using chrome in ubuntu and everything goes well even those examples in w3schools.

Comment: So basically this has to put into consideration as well while using CSS animations. Just saying.