# webkit-animation-iteration-count works only on INFINITE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Assuming this css works ONLY on chrome (i've tested on chrome beta 41.* and actually on 40.0.2214.111 m)

Consider a simple box and a css ":hover" fires a pulse (scale) animation on it.

Here the code

```
.box{
   background-color:black;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   top:25px;
   left:25px;
}
.box:hover{
   -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse{
    0% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

(jsfiddle here: [livedemo](http://jsfiddle.net/26qf5a4r/))

As you can see this works without iusse on Chrome... but my point is to repeat this animation only 1 time and not infinite.

So lets change the `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;` into `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;` (try it on jsfiddle live demo previosly posted) and the iusse cames out!

Basically if i dont set -webkit-animation-iteration-count to infinite the animation will fired too FAST even apart from explicit number setted!

Any advice is appreciated!

...and just to let u know...
 1. I've searched it on chrome bugtrack without results.
 2. I've serched here without results except for this post without answere [Webkit animation-iteration-count bug in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901272/webkit-animation-iteration-count-bug-in-chrome?s=2%7C4.5658)
 3. This code works until last month (i dont remember the exact day when it starts to fail)
 4. If i restart my pc this iusse will NOT appear for 1 or 2 times .. but after a few page-refresh i cant able to play animation witn interaction count != infinite!

EDIT: Tested on Chrome Canary Version 42.0.2298.0 canary (64-bit) and it WORKS perfectly... so i guess this error will disappear after a few Chrome standatd updates.

PS: sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Working fine for me =/

Comment: I've asked to some friends of mine and it works for them too... i suspect it is a Graphic-Driver-Chrome related iussue.... I've resintalled my nvidia video driver and restarted the PC and it WORKS for few times but now the iussue appears again!!!! i dont figure how solve this...!

Comment: Iussue solved on Chrome 41.